# Laravel/Voyager: Send email when new data is created using BREAD

Tags: php, laravel, email, events, voyager

I have a coupons table BREAD with Voyager whereby each coupon will have an email address. I would like to send an email to the specific email address which is associated with the coupon when a new coupon has been created.

Coupons table:

[image]

For example from the above picture, after I have created the coupon named: haha123, I would like to send an email to cdn@gmail.com.

As I didn't make a custom controller for generating new coupon and has been only using the default BREAD function from Voyager, hence I am unsure where and how should I do it.

**SOLVED:**

This is most likely not the best way as I didn't make use of the voyager events. Hence, I just do it the troublesome way by adding my own custom voyager CouponsController to overwrite the default controller and add the laravel mail function in the store method of within the custom CouponsController.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe helpful, Send email when model status updated (Laravel Voyager Admin)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Mail;

class Contact extends Model
{
    public $table = 'contacts';
    public $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'message'];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::updating(function ($contact) {
            if ($contact->status == 1) {
                Mail::send(
                    'email',
                    array(
                        'name' => $contact->name,
                        'email' => $contact->email,
                        'bodyMessage' => $contact->message
                    ),
                    function ($message) use ($contact) {
                        $message->from($contact->email);
                        $message->to('email_address@email.com', 'Name')->subject('Your request status updated');
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Voyager just makes your work easy. It creates the model and the controller for you in laravel. You will find the controller and the models in the same place as a custom model or controller created using artisan. I hope it helps.

If you have more questions, please be specific about the issue you are facing.

Cheers

Comment: I have my own couponscontroller which is to validate the coupon when the customer uses the coupon on my checkout page, but this is not related to Voyager or creating new coupon. I left it blank on the controller name field in Coupons BREAD info in Voyager hence there isn't any couponscontroller made by Voyager in my app/http/controllers/voyager folder. My question is how can I achieve the example that I have stated in my 1st post.

Answer (score 0):

You could very simply hook into the lifecycle of the Coupon model with an event listener:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events

First tell the model to fire the `CouponCreated` event when a new model is created

```
use App\Events\CouponCreated;

class Coupon extends Model
{
    /**
     * The event map for the model.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'created' => CouponCreated::class
    ];
}
```

That event will be passed the `Coupon` model which you can use to send the email.

If you want more specific help you'd need to post code.  I am sure you could also just do this in the `create` method of the CouponController if you hunt that down.

Comment: Yeah I was going to use the 2nd method you stated by just adding in the `create` method, however I just couldn't find it. Here is a screenshot of my directory and the codes in my CouponsController: https://imgur.com/a/UWwAZ0h

Comment: @TohJeuLun look for the method in the class your controller extends. Then you can overwrite that method on your controller and add the code you need

Comment: Or is there a way to link the events provided by voyager as listed here: https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/tree/1.0/src/Events ? As the BREAD method should be in the vendor folder which wouldn't be a good idea to modify from there.

There is a similar scenario here but still don't know how to do it in my case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971115/laravel-voyager-bread-on-submit-send-message